# Setting CSS classes as a variable in Javascript for later use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to know if it's possible to set a CSS class e.g. ".duck" as a variable in javascript using jquery e.g. `var duck = $(".duck");`

I've done this with the "body" tag and with CSS ID's but it doesn't seem to work with any kind of a class.

I want to set it as a variable for later use, I have the ID "#frog" set as "var frog = $("#frog");" so in my javascript I can type

```
frog.moveTo(0);
frog.speed(0.3);
frog.autoBounceOff(true);
```

But for the duck class I still have to use

```
$(".duck").moveTo(270);
$(".duck").speed(0.65);
$(".duck").onCollision(function(otherObj){
```

Is it possible to set classes as a variable?

Comment: `var duck = $(".duck");` should work, so your answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, but it won't work as you expect it to work. When you do `$(".duck")` it'll pick up all elements with that class *at that moment*. jQuery collections never update automatically when the DOM changes, so you can't make a variable that'll always refer to all the *current* elements with that class.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why `var duck = $(".duck");` would not work, unless there is an error elsewhere in your code. Check the console to see if this is the case.

Comment: Can u also show the HTML code for the same ?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing related to CSS here.

- `duck` is an HTML class.
- `.duck` is a class selector.
- `$(".duck")` is a function call that returns a jQuery object (containing all the DOM elements, in the document, that are members of the class at the time the function is called).

You can store the return value of a function call in a variable.

A common convention is to store jQuery objects in variables with names starting with a `$`.

```
var $duck = $(".duck");
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but the OP says that `var duck = $(".duck");` doesn't work so this is unlikely to solve the actual problem.

Comment: I have duck set as a class with CSS elements

`.duck { 
background-image: url('images/duck.png'); 
position: fixed; 
width: 51.03px; 
height: 49.21px; 
background-size: 51.03px 49.21px; 
z-index: 1; 
left: 100vw; 
top: 43vh;}`
I tried substituting duck with $duck but I have the same response, everything else works but the ducks don't appear and move as I've set them to.